# Change child parent in GameKit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am working on an arrow shooting game - The player need to shoot 3 arrows to a moving target (the target moves from left to right). When an arrow hits the target it should move with it (left to right). The most obvious thing to do would be to change the arrow parent to the target. From some reason its causing me some troubles -

1. I tried --- arrow.move(toParent:target) and I don't see the arrow on the screen even after I set a new location for it
2. If I simply --- target.addChild(arrow) I get a failure since I did not remove the arrow from its parent (which is the scene in this case)
3. When I --- arrow.removeFromParent() and then target.addChild(arrow) its causing other arrows to collide with each other and I still don't see the arrow on the screen.

This is my code -

```
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

var target:SKSpriteNode?
var arrows = [SKSpriteNode]()
var arrowContactPoint:CGPoint?

let noCategory:UInt32 = 0
let arrowCategory:UInt32 = 0b1
let targetCategory:UInt32 = 0b1 << 1
let obstacleCategory:UInt32 = 0b1 << 2

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    allowCollisionDetection()
    setTarget()
    moveTargetFromSideToSide()
    newArrow()
}

func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    let categoryBitMaskBodyA:UInt32 = contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask
    let categoryBitMaskBodyB:UInt32 = contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask

    if ((categoryBitMaskBodyA == targetCategory && categoryBitMaskBodyB == arrowCategory) || (categoryBitMaskBodyA == arrowCategory && categoryBitMaskBodyB == targetCategory)) {
        arrowContactPoint = contact.contactPoint
        arrowCollideWithTarget()
    } else if (categoryBitMaskBodyA == obstacleCategory || categoryBitMaskBodyB == obstacleCategory) {
        let obstacleNode:SKNode = ((categoryBitMaskBodyA == arrowCategory) ? contact.bodyA.node! : contact.bodyB.node)!
        arrowCollideWithObstacle(obstacle:obstacleNode)
    } else if (categoryBitMaskBodyA == arrowCategory && categoryBitMaskBodyB == arrowCategory) {
        newGame()
    } else {
        print("Something went wrong")
    }

    newArrow()
}

func touchDown(atPoint pos : CGPoint) {

}

func touchMoved(toPoint pos : CGPoint) {

}

func touchUp(atPoint pos : CGPoint) {
    shootArrow()
}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for t in touches { self.touchDown(atPoint: t.location(in: self)) }
}

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for t in touches { self.touchMoved(toPoint: t.location(in: self)) }
}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for t in touches { self.touchUp(atPoint: t.location(in: self)) }
}

override func touchesCancelled(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for t in touches { self.touchUp(atPoint: t.location(in: self)) }
}

override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
    // Called before each frame is rendered

}

func allowCollisionDetection() {
    self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
}

func setTarget() {
    target = self.childNode(withName: "target") as? SKSpriteNode
    //Set the target bit mask, it's tag
    target?.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = targetCategory
    //Set with which objects the target collide
    target?.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = noCategory
    //Set to which coliision we want to responde/handle - didBegin will get triggered
    target?.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = arrowCategory
}

func moveTargetFromSideToSide() {
    let moveRight = SKAction.moveBy(x: frame.size.width - (target?.size.width)!, y: 0, duration: 2)
    let moveLeft = SKAction.moveBy(x: -(frame.size.width - (target?.size.width)!), y: 0, duration: 2)
    let moveBackAndForth = SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.sequence([moveRight, moveLeft]))
    target?.run(moveBackAndForth)
}

func newArrow() {
    let arrow = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "arrow1")
    let arrowTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "arrow1")
    arrow.position = CGPoint.zero
    self.addChild(arrow)
    arrow.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: arrowTexture, size: arrowTexture.size())
    arrow.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
    arrow.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = true
    arrow.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    arrow.physicsBody?.friction = 0.2
    arrow.physicsBody?.restitution = 0.2
    arrow.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0.1
    arrow.physicsBody?.angularDamping = 0.1
    arrow.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0)
    arrow.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = arrowCategory
    arrow.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = noCategory
    arrow.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = arrowCategory | obstacleCategory | targetCategory
    arrows.append(arrow)
}

func shootArrow(){
    print("shootArrow")
    arrows.last!.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 80))
}

func arrowCollideWithTarget() {
    print("arrowCollideWithTarget")
    arrows.last!.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0)
    arrows.last!.move(toParent: target!)
}

func arrowCollideWithObstacle(obstacle:SKNode) {
    print("arrowCollideWithObstacle")
    arrows.last!.removeFromParent()
    arrows.removeLast()
}

func newGame() {
    print("New Game")
    for i in 0 ..< (arrows.count) {
        arrows[i].removeFromParent()
    }
    arrows.removeAll()
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What eventually solved it for me was using this method --- 
move(toParent: )

This is my code -

```
func arrowCollideWithTarget() {
    arrows.last!.move(toParent:target!)
}
```